# Compare Features between client side sorting and SQL Server sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

When it comes to sort some data, we have two option to sort the data:
first one is   sort on  SQL server  with  ORDER BY clause, and   another is 
  Client  side sorting ,how i can choose one option over the other  and
 why? which option is more efficient ?what are the feature will help
 with sorting? is there any sorting function with client side sorting ?
what is the adventage on client  side sorting?

Comment: Does paging come into the mix?  That could lock you into sorting on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting data in SQL server is faster than client side but getting data from SQL server and binding data to client side will add cost and hence this process  more take time than Sorting on client side. I would suggest you to sort data on client side and use some JavaScript framework like Jquery. You have not mention what plateform you are using as front end

Have a look some jquery based sorting example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TableBlueSorter.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=259